# Can entries disabled by default in Guest Entries plugin and in section be enabled from the front-end?

Tags: plugin-guestentries

So I have the switch for *Enable entries by Default* set to OFF for [Guest Entries](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries) and a channel.

Given this `value="1"` for input field `name="enabled"` on Guest Entry submission I always get entry **not updated** in corresponding field with desired value.

```
{# Enable entry #}
<input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">
```

I think the channel switch for *Enable entries by default* should be on as guest entries doesn't have control over that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, that won't work.

The Guest Entries plugin looks at the plugin's setting for whether that entry should be enabled for the given section or not, not anything from $_POST.

https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries/blob/master/guestentries/controllers/GuestEntriesController.php#L227

Comment: So some plugin modification needs to be done. Thanks @brad